# Put "choose" brackets in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I want to write about the binomial distribution in a rmd document but I cannot work out how to represent the large bracket which surround two values written above one another. (Reads x choose y)
Any thoughts?
Tried various configurations of "choose" and "binom" but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

Using RStudio, this is what my .Rmd file looks like:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "sahir"
date: "March 12, 2015"
output: html_document
---

$$P(X \leq k) = \sum_{y \leq k} \binom{n}{y} p^y (1-p)^{n-y}$$
```